# Get base url in dev and production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using MVC3 and building an a tag (link) using jquery.  The problem is I can only get my links to work in either prod or dev, not both.  Here is my site's url in production.

http://tvap.mydomain.com

This is my development url.
http://localhost/TVAP

So, I have a link that I'm creating via jquery as follows.

```
  var actionCell = $('#itemlist').find(rowId).find(actionCellId);
  $('<a>Edit</a>').attr({ 'id': 'edit-' + response.id, 'href': '/Items/Edit/' + response.id }).appendTo(actionCell);
```

In production, this works, and creates a link as

```
 <a id="edit-17" href="/Items/Edit/17">
```

But in development (local) it doesn't work as I need this.

```
 <a id="edit-17" href="/TVAP/ItemManagement/Edit/17">
```

I get the following from

```
 $(location).attr('host') ==> localhost
 $(location).attr('host') ==> http://localhost/TVAP/Items/Index
```

Either too little, or too much info.  I'd know I can check for localhost and append TVAP as needed, but this seems like a hack.  Another developer may use the ASP.NET VS dev server and get a URL will contain localhost but without the TVAP as I'm getting.
i.e. - http://localhost:64301/Items/Index

Comment: Why is your API localed on Items on and ItemManagement in development?
Clean that up. Use identical API's, otherwise you are just adding potential errors to your code.
When you are done doing that, change the urls to be page relative instead of root relative, then you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I always do in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.myProjectName = {
            baseUrl : '@Url.Content("~/")'
        };
    </script>
    <!-- other scripts -->
</head>
```

Then you can always use stuff like `myProjectName.baseUrl+"Controller/Action"` for accessing your resources from your own javascript files. This helps you separate the views from the javascript, which is a really good thing.

You don't want to mix markup and javascript - and this is a compromise that goes a long way.

Comment: Great idea. I've updated my _Layout.cshtml file. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

If your JS is directly inside your view (as opposed to an external JS file), you can just use Razor to flush URLs into your Javascript.

```
// untested
var actionCell = $('#itemlist').find(rowId).find(actionCellId);
$('<a>Edit</a>').attr({ 
    'id': 'edit-' + response.id, 
    'href': '@Url.Action("Edit")/' + response.id
}).appendTo(actionCell);
```